# Can I add code/update my exported app in windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms, setup-wizard

So I made a Quick Notes app in Visual Studio using C# and the **windows forms .NET Framework**. I exported the program using the **setup wizard** which is part of the **Microsoft visual studio installer projects extension**.
The app is completed but I forgot to add a bit of code. I can add it in visual studio since the project is still there but I'm not sure it will apply it to the **exported app.**

Can anyone help?

I don't want to break anything so I haven't written any new code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any workflow that generates an installer (.msi, .msix, setup.exe) will need to be regenerated if code changes are made to the installed app. The installer version should be incremented and also a new `ProductCode` should be generated so that the newer installer has the information it needs to remove prior versions.